# Как убрать знаки пунктуации python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, случайные-числа

Есть вот такой код. Он выводит 12 рандомных слов из словаря. Мне нужно убрать любые знаки, то есть оставить только слова через пробел.

```
import random

with open('word_list.txt', 'r') as file:
    words = file.readlines()
    words = [s.strip("\n") for s in words]

# Выбираеем рандомные слова
how_many_words = 12
print (random.sample(words, how_many_words))
```

Мой вывод:

```
['volume', 'spike', 'soldier', 'final', 'oblige', 'doll', 'rebuild', 'lounge', 'exchange', 'wage', 'quick', 'question']
```

Желаемый вывод:

```
volume spike soldier final oblige doll rebuild lounge exchange wage quick question
```

Answer (score 4):

В твоём случае это не знаки пунктуации, а отображение [объекта списка в виде строки](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html).

Для того чтобы получить требуемый формат ты можешь соединить все элементы списка с помощью функции [`join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) с пробелом в качестве разделителя.

```
random_words = random.sample(words, how_many_words)
print(" ".join(random_words))
```

Comment: Или ещё проще - `print(*random.sample(words, how_many_words))`.

Answer (score 1):

просто как небольшое дополнение к другим ответам: судя по коду из вопроса, каждая строка файла - 1 слово, тогда, используя pandas, можно немного упростить код, примерно так:

```
import pandas as pd

how_many_words = 12
print(pd.read_csv('test.txt', header=None).sample(how_many_words)[0].str.cat(sep=' '))
```